# Proving an equality involving the floor function

Tags: ceiling-and-floor-functions

> Show that
>
> $\left \lfloor \dfrac{ \lfloor x \rfloor+m }{n} \right \rfloor =
>  \left \lfloor \dfrac{x+m}{n} \right \rfloor$, where m is an
> arbitrary integer and $ n$ is an integer $> 0$.

Let us start with splitting up the fraction:

$$\left\lfloor\frac{\lfloor x\rfloor +m}{n}\right\rfloor=\left\lfloor\frac{\lfloor x\rfloor}{n}+\frac{m}{n}\right\rfloor$$
We have the equality $\lfloor x\rfloor = x-\{x\}$. Since $n$ and $m$ are constants, we can use this rule on the splitted fraction above, so that we can write:

$$\frac{\lfloor x\rfloor}{n}=\frac{x}{n}-\frac{\{x\}}{n},$$
Then inserting this in the top equality, we get:

$$\left\lfloor\frac{\lfloor x\rfloor +m}{n}\right\rfloor=\left\lfloor\frac{x}{n}+\frac{m-\{x\}}{n}\right\rfloor$$

Then merge the two fractions:

$$\left\lfloor\frac{\lfloor x\rfloor +m}{n}\right\rfloor=\left\lfloor\frac{x+m-\{x\}}{n}\right\rfloor$$

Since $\{x\}$ is a part of the fraction $\frac{m-\{x\}}{n}$, we can set the equality:

$$\frac{m-\{x\}}{n}=\left\lfloor\frac{m}{n}\right\rfloor,$$

and obtain:

$$\left\lfloor\frac{\lfloor x\rfloor +m}{n}\right\rfloor=\left\lfloor\frac{x+m}{n}\right\rfloor$$

However, I am not sure if the last step requires additional intermediary steps, and if this last step holds at all.

Any comments welcomed.

Thanks

Comment: $\frac{m-\{x\}}{n}=\left\lfloor\frac{m}{n}\right\rfloor$ looks wrong if for example $m=n$ and $\{x\}>0$

Comment: Yes, it is true, but if I use the equality $$\left\lfloor \frac{x+m-\{x\}}{n}\right\rfloor =\left\lfloor \frac{x+m}{n}\right\rfloor$$ it should be true. But why?

Comment: Why not let $k= \left \lfloor \dfrac{x+m}{n} \right \rfloor$ (an integer) so $nk \le x+m \lt n(k+1)$ and show $nk \le \lfloor x \rfloor +m \lt n(k+1)$ too